# Why do I get error: run npm ci & run npm build failed when pushing changes to React app that is deployed on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, continuous-integration

Here's a link to the repo for better readability:
https://github.com/shaynemcp/reactCounterDemo/runs/7507090095?check_suite_focus=true

[fail run npm ci & npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMLyp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is already in the logs. Your build treats warnings as errors and your eslint warns of the list of unused variables.

Delete the variables in the mentioned files or make them used and you should be fine.

Edit: looking at your `index.js` you seem to do imports but never use the imports. So you should remove unused imports.

Comment: thank you so much just a silly mistake on my end!

Answer (score 0):

As Laluka said, As it states in logs: `Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.` You could change environmental variable 'CI' to false, or you could fix whatever the warnings are.

Comment: thank you so much. I tried @Laluku response and it solved my build issue.